# Insert user email logged into a site within a screen flow

Tags: data

I have created a screen flow with a form within a site with salesforce, I would like to automatically take the email of the logged in user so as to insert it automatically when I create a new record, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly;

You could assign the field to `{!$User.Email}` within the flow. This will automatically take the email of the logged in user

Comment: Can I do it through get record?

Comment: $User is a standard variable given in the context of the flow. If you want to use it in a get record to retrieve something (like the whole user or another object) you can do that but you can use it directly in a create record if you just need the email.

Comment: It works, thank you so much

Comment: No problem! Could you mark this as the accepted answer, please?